# How to implement Django-like tags in Jinja

Tags: python, django, jinja2

I would like to implement similar functionality to Django template's custom tags in Jinja.

In Django templates, to have a server-side function return a string and have it inserted to a template, you can do something as simple as this:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.inclusion_tag('app/gallery.html')
def get_gallery(active=None):
    ### do complex server side things, etc.

    context_dict = {
        ...
    }
    return context_dict
```

Now, calling this is as simple as

```
{% load app_tags %}
{% get_gallery 'home' %}
```

This seems clear and simple enough for me.

Now my question: even after reading through all parts of the Jinja2 documentation, I do not see how a similar functionality should be implemented in Jinja. I've seen that Jinja supports macros, calls, imports, custom tests, custom filters, but I cannot see anything related to defining custom tags with arbitrary server-side Python code.

The closest I've seen is custom filters, but that has a weird syntax when used for tag-like purposes: to call `tag(param1, param2)`, you'd need to write `param1|tag(param2)`. Also, I don't see how it can be used for parameter-less functions.

There is also the whole extension support, but that seems overly complicated with the [simplest example](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/extensions/#example-extension) taking up 56 lines of code in the doc.

Can you explain how do you solve this problem, both in standalone Jinja2 environment (think static site generation), and under the new Django versions (1.8+)?

Answer (score 1):

You don't write custom tags in Jinja for these things. Instead, you just register the `get_gallery` function as a global Jinja variable and call it from your templates:

```
{{ get_gallery('home') | safe }}
```

Instead of a global variable, in Flask you can also declare a "context processor", but the idea is the same http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/templating/#context-processors

--- **UPDATE** ---

The function could be something like this:

```
def get_gallery(gallery_uuid):
    ### do complex server side things, etc.

    return render_template(
        'app/gallery.html',
        foo=bar,
    )
```

The template will print anything the function returns.
The function doesn't know which template is calling it or the template context, just what you pass as arguments.

Comment: What will  be the 'get_gallery' function like?  How can we indicate the template path, context, in the function?